# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar varios componentes de la clase `java.swing.JCheckBox` para que desplegue la hora usando Map?

Tags: java, java-swing

Mi objetivo es usar varios `Checkbox`y activarlos de manera que se dibujen los números y así obtener la hora a partir de la clase `Calendar` o la clase `Date` .
Quisiera aclarar más la pregunta: Quiero que los `CheckBox`se marquen/activen relacionándolo tal vez con un mapeo y de ahí poder determinar cuáles se activan y cuáles no, pero haciendo que de lejos parezca un reloj,más o menos así:

[image: Reloj marcando las 12:00]

Comment: Hey pana y como formas los checkbox para que formen el numero, tienes varios checkbox en tu panel o tienes una matrix de checkbox?

Comment: podrias hacer un video? por que realmente esta interesante ese proyecto, saludos

Comment: El proyecto lo terminé. Fue bastante complicado al principio. Aún quieres el video, @jose?

Comment: Tengo varios *CheckBox* en el panel @JOhansel Estevez

Comment: @BrianMartínez me alegro que hayas encontrado la respuesta y la hayas publicado, pero tal y como está la pregunta era imposible saber cómo tenías el código (aparte del bucle donde se crean los checkboxes porque se ve en la captura) y era imposible ayudarte. Te recomendaría que en futuras publicaciones agregases un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) que pueda ser de ayud para toda la comunidad.

Comment: Gracias @AlvaroMontoro. Lo tomaré en cuenta la próxima vez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución.

- Primero obtengo la hora, los minutos y los segundos mediante la clase `GregorianCalendar` y `Date` para asignarle la hora a Calendar:

  ```
  @Override
  public void run() {
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    Date now = new Date();

    cal.setTime(now);
  ```
- Luego asigno los valores a las variables `Int hora, minuto y segundo;` con Calendar:

  ```
   hora = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
   minuto = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
   .
   .
  ```

  Así sucesivamente. Y entonces debajo de cada una de las variables hago un switch que las analice con valores de 0-1 (por el método `HOUR` que es diferente a `HOUR_OF_DAY` que es desde 0-24). El switch tendrá los casos correspondientes y ahí entonces activo los CheckBox para que forme el "00" en caso de que sean las doce.